# Kiwi TCMS: Upload problem with certain files

Tags: kiwi-tcms, kiwi-template

**Details:**
We have installed the Kiwi TCMS it also works very well. But we have a problem uploading scripts.

**More information:**
We have seen this post here, know that for security reasons certain scripts are not allowed to be uploaded. - https://github.com/kiwitcms/Kiwi/security/advisories/GHSA-fwcf-753v-fgcj

**Question:**

Where can I find in the latest Kiwi tcms version the possibility to allow certain files?